# How is Tibco EMS client licensed?

Tags: .net, client, libraries, tibco, tibco-ems

What I need to install when developing application (I'm using .NET but it should be same for other platforms) with connectivity to TIBCO EMS? I have TIBCO EMS install package but it installs whole server. How does it work with client applications connecting to EMS? Do I have to install TIBCO EMS server on every machine just to get client libraries or is it allowed to copy libraries from the real server to clients?

For example when developing connectivity to IBM WebSphere MQ I just need to install WebSphere MQ Client which can connect to licensed MQ Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TIBCO EMS does not have a developer install or client library install. You will need to use the installer provided as part of the TIBCO EMS download. From a purely technical point of view, it would be possible to copy the required files from the server, however it is unlikely that this would be supported and you would need to check that doing so does not violate your licensing.

In terms of licensing, TIBCO offers perpetual licenses for production, non-production and developer use. You should contact your TIBCO account representative to obtain pricing. Let me know if you need help doing this.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to connect to the ems server you only need. To reference the ems dll in your project.  We have been doing this for many years.    We also use the tems dll which is used with wcf.   This helps bw/java/salesforce consume the wsdl by flattening it.

Comment: Yes but is it valid usage in terms of licensing? If Tibco wants to do it this way they would simply create free redistributable client installation package with all necessary libraries.

Comment: yes,  I do agree.  However with some big companies your organization may have negotiated some deal on licensing.  You will need o check with your TIBCO account rep on your deal.  I know we have pretty much unlimited use of our EMS server and are not licensed for the client DLL, our purchasing department may have negotiated this in.  We also have some clause in our contract about if its in Production on Day "X" from signing the contract its licensed forever, and your support cost is based on what you have in production.

Comment: Several tibco consultants we had onsite stated that Dev/QA were free rain and we could have as many EMS Servers, BW, Tibco Admin, Service Grid, CIM, Spotfire, as we wanted or needed,  Thus each developer could have everything installed.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you can get a copy of the TIBCO.EMS.dll and use it in applications as needed without a consideration for licensing. The reason is that the assembly is only useful if you have an EMS instance to which you can connect. The EMS server itself is generally licensed by the core. So, you are still going to end up adding load to EMS and will have to pay for it.

One other thing to note is that if you run a local instance of EMS for development purposes, that must normally be licensed. Brian's experience that you can do what you want in QA/Dev and not have to worry about licensing does not align with what we've been told. However, I believe that TIBCO does offer some all-you-can-eat type licenses at a premium and it is likely that they just have a different agreement in place and therefore it is allowed in his environment.

Disclaimer - Your TIBCO account rep is going to be the best source for a definitive answer.